# Callbaks и цикл for

Tags: javascript

Есть цыкл и внутри него есть асинхронная функция, будет ли цикл ждать завершения всех функция, или он просто их выполнит и пойдет дальше ?

```
for (let link of links) {
      request(`${VK_CHECKER_LINK}${link.get('referer')}`, (err, response, body) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        let statusVK = body.response.status;

        vkLinksCheck.push({
          link.status_vk = DomainsReferersStatus.getStatus(statusVK);
        });
      });
    }

    callback(null, vkLinksCheck);
```

То есть callback может выполнится до того как придет ответ с асинхронной функции в цикле ?

Comment: нет, ждать не будет, и `callback` вызовется раньше чем обработчики переданные в _request_

Comment: @Grundy не совсем дубликат. Тут надо дождаться нескольких событий, а не одного - на эту тему отдельный вопрос нужен.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, мне кажется лучше добавить в секцию про обещания описание `Promise.all`

Comment: @Grundy там надо по всем способам реализацию ожидания нескольких событий приводить

Comment: @PavelMayorov, вот даже не знаю тогда :-)